# Table-Valued Parameter as Output parameter for stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, t-sql, datatypes, parameter

Is it possibile to Table-Valued parameter be used as output param for stored procedure ?

Here is, what I want to do in code

```
/*First I create MY type */
CREATE TYPE typ_test AS TABLE 
(
     id int not null
    ,name varchar(50) not null
    ,value varchar(50) not null
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
GO


--Now I want to create stored procedu whic is going to send output type I created, 
--But it looks like it is inpossible, at least in SQL2008
create  PROCEDURE [dbo].sp_test
         @od datetime 
        ,@do datetime 
        ,@poruka varchar(Max) output
        ,@iznos money output 
        ,@racun_stavke  dbo.typ_test   READONLY --Can I Change READONLY with OUTPUT ?
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    /*FILL MY OUTPUT PARAMS AS I LIKE */


    end
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

No, unfortunately table value parameters are read-only and input only. This topic in general is covered very well in [How to Share Data between Stored Procedures](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html), which presents all the alternatives. My recommendation would be to use a `#temp` table.

Answer (score 3):

in addition to [the nicely put answer by remus](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/13796/22336) including the link he provided

[How to Share Data between Stored Procedures](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html)

there are situations where you get the following error messages when saving the results of a stored procedure to a table:

[An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795263/errors-insert-exec-statement-cannot-be-nested-and-cannot-use-the-rollback-s)

[The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7490088/1501497)

and when this happens on my own stored procedures that I develop for my own use

for example a tool to tell me from a `login` all the AD groups it belongs to and all their permissions in all databases in a server

I create a temp table outside the procedure and pass its name as a parameter

```
--===============
-- this way below it works, by passing a temp table as a parameter
--===============

                if OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#my_table') IS NOT NULL
                   DROP TABLE #my_table

                CREATE TABLE #my_table(
                    db nvarchar(128)   COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS  NULL,
                   permission_type nvarchar(128)   COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS  NULL,
                    login_  nvarchar(128)   COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS  NULL,
                    role_  nvarchar(128)   COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS  NULL,
                    Obj    nvarchar(517)   COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS  NULL,
                    Permission nvarchar(128)   COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS  NULL,
                    script nvarchar(1008)  COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS  NULL
                ) 

                exec sp_GetLoginDBPermissionsX 
                    @Login='my_loginname', 
                    @debug=0,
                    @where_to_save ='#my_table'

                select *
                from #my_table
```

and inside the procedure, after all the calculations, when I am returning the final data (below an example)
I check whether we are outputting to a table or just back to the screen and create the script dynamically.

```
            select @sql = case when @where_to_save IS not null then 
            '
            insert into ' + @where_to_save + '(db,Permission_Type,login_,role_,obj,Permission,script) '
            else '' end + 
'
        SELECT 
            J.db,
            J.Permission_Type,
            J.login_,
            J.role_,
            J.Obj,
            J.Permission,
            J.script
        FROM #tablewithpermissions J
        WHERE J.login_ IN ( SELECT  L1.LOGIN_FROM COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS FROM #logins L1)
           OR J.role_ IN  ( SELECT  L1.LOGIN_FROM COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS FROM #logins L1)
       ORDER BY J.DB, J.[permission_order]
'
        --print(@sql)

        EXEC(@SQL)
```

After that you have either the info you need on the screen, or if you have passed a temp table as a parameter, it will have the data now.

this is one solution I found, but I only use it for my own works `DBA` otherwise this will be considered high risk for [Sql Injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/sql-injection?view=sql-server-2017).

Answer (score 2):

This is an older post, but it was near the top when I was searching for "Table-Valued Parameter as Output parameter for stored procedure".  While it is my understanding that you cannot pass a table-valued parameter as an output parameter, I would imagine the goal is to use that table-valued output parameter as a table-valued input parameter in another procedure.  I will show an example for how I made this work.

First, create some data to work with:

```
create table tbl1
(
id int,
fname varchar(10),
gender varchar(10)
);
create table tbl2
(
id int,
lname varchar(10)
);
insert into tbl1
values
(1,'bob'  ,'m'),
(2,'tom'  ,'m'),
(3,'sally','f')
;
insert into tbl2
values
(1,'jones'   ),
(2,'johnson' ),
(3,'smith'   )
;
```

Next, create a stored procedure to capture some of the data.  Normally, this would be where you are trying to create a table-valued output parameter.

```
create procedure usp_OUTPUT1
 @gender varchar(10)
as
Begin
    select id from tbl1 where gender = @gender
End
```

Additionally, you will want to create a data type (table type) where the data from the first stored procedure can be passed as the input parameter for the next stored procedure.

```
create type tblType as Table (id int)
```

Next, create the second stored procedure that will accept the table-valued parameter.

```
create procedure usp_OUTPUT2
@tblType tblType readonly  --referencing the type created and specify readonly
as
begin
 select lname from tbl2 where id in (select id from @tblType)
end
```

Granted, this is not a true table-valued output parameter, but it will likely produce results similar to what you would be looking for. Declare your table-valued parameter, fill it with data by executing the stored procedure into it, then use it as the input variable for the next procedure.

```
Declare @tblType tblType 
insert into @tblType execute usp_OUTPUT1 'm'
execute usp_OUTPUT2 @tblType
```

Answer (score 0):

A table could be converted to JSON (SQL Server 2016 or later) and passed as an nvarchar parameter out:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test
  @json nvarchar(max) output
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  --Create table variable
  declare @t1 as table ([value] nvarchar(max), [ordinal] int);

  --Fill table
  INSERT INTO @t1 ([value], [ordinal])
  SELECT 'abc', 1 UNION
  SELECT 'def', 2;

  --Convert table to JSON
  set @json  = (SELECT * FROM @t1 FOR JSON PATH);
END
```

[{"value":"abc","ordinal":1},{"value":"def","ordinal":2}]

Then to convert it back to a table, specify the column names as JSON keys:

```
declare @json nvarchar(max);

exec test @json output;

--Convert JSON to table
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json)
WITH ([value] nvarchar(max) '$.value', [ordinal] int '$.ordinal');
```