# alternatives to passing temp table as a parameter to a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql, parameter, table-valued-parameters

some time ago I was developing a simple procedure to get the database sizes on a particular server. Here it is the procedure:

```
USE MASTER
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.sp_getDBSpace
    @Radhe sysname=null,
    @system_only BIT = NULL ,
    @user_only BIT = NULL ,
    @database_list NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL ,
    @exclude_list NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL ,
    @recovery_model_desc NVARCHAR(120) = NULL ,
    @compatibility_level TINYINT = NULL ,
    @state_desc NVARCHAR(120) = N'ONLINE' ,
    @is_read_only BIT = 0 ,
    @is_auto_close_on BIT = NULL ,
    @is_auto_shrink_on BIT = NULL ,
    @is_broker_enabled BIT = NULL 
AS

BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON
SET XACT_ABORT ON
SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY NORMAL;

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)


                    SET @sql = N'USE [?]

                    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
                    ;with radhe as (

                    SELECT 
                    Servername   = @@servername,
                    DatabaseName = DB_NAME(), 

                    a.FILE_ID, 
                    a.type, -- 0 is log and 1 is data

                    [Drive] = LEFT(UPPER(a.physical_name), 1), 

                    [FILE_SIZE_GB] = CONVERT(DECIMAL(12, 2), ROUND(a.size / 128.000/1024.000, 2)), 

                    [SPACE_USED_GB] = CONVERT(DECIMAL(12, 2), ROUND(FILEPROPERTY(a.NAME, ''SpaceUsed'') / 128.000/1024.000, 2)), 

                    [FREE_SPACE_GB] = CONVERT(DECIMAL(12, 2), ROUND((a.size - FILEPROPERTY(a.NAME, ''SpaceUsed'')) / 128.000/1024.000, 2)), 

                    a.NAME, 
                    a.PHYSICAL_NAME AS [FILENAME]

                    FROM sys.database_files a
                    )

                        insert into ' + @Radhe + N'([ServerName],[DatabaseName],[Drive],[FILE_ID],[FILE_SIZE_GB],[SPACE_USED_GB],[FREE_SPACE_GB],[NAME],[FILENAME],[TOTAL_DATABASE_SIZE])
                        SELECT 
                                             [ServerName]           
                                            ,[DatabaseName]         
                                            ,[Drive]                
                                            ,[FILE_ID]              
                                            ,[FILE_SIZE_GB]         
                                            ,[SPACE_USED_GB]        
                                            ,[FREE_SPACE_GB]        
                                            ,[NAME]                 
                                            ,[FILENAME]    
                                            ,TOTAL_DATABASE_SIZE      = SUM([FILE_SIZE_GB] ) OVER (PARTITION BY A.DATABASENAME )
                                            --,SPACE_USED               = SUM([SPACE_USED_GB] ) OVER (PARTITION BY A.DATABASENAME )
                                            --,TOTAL_FREE_LOG_SPACE_GB  = SUM(CASE WHEN A.TYPE = 0 THEN [FREE_SPACE_GB] ELSE 0 END ) OVER (PARTITION BY A.DATABASENAME )
                                            --,TOTAL_FREE_DATA_SPACE_GB = SUM(CASE WHEN A.TYPE = 1 THEN [FREE_SPACE_GB] ELSE 0 END ) OVER (PARTITION BY A.DATABASENAME )
                         FROM radhe a


                            '

             exec sp_foreachdb 
                    @system_only = @system_only,
                    @user_only = @user_only,
                    @database_list = @database_list,
                    @exclude_list = @exclude_list,
                    @recovery_model_desc = @recovery_model_desc,
                    @compatibility_level = @compatibility_level,
                    @state_desc = @state_desc,
                    @is_read_only = @is_read_only ,
                    @is_auto_close_on = @is_auto_close_on,
                    @is_auto_shrink_on = @is_auto_shrink_on ,
                    @is_broker_enabled = @is_broker_enabled
                  ,@command=@SQL 

END
GO
```

And here is how I used to call this procedure:

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Radhe') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #Radhe
    GO
    CREATE TABLE #Radhe( 
    [ServerName]           NVARCHAR(128)                        NULL,
    [DatabaseName]         NVARCHAR(128)                        NULL,
    [Drive]                NVARCHAR(1)                          NULL,
    [FILE_ID]              INT                                  NOT NULL,
    [FILE_SIZE_GB]         DECIMAL(12,2)                        NULL,
    [SPACE_USED_GB]        DECIMAL(12,2)                        NULL,
    [FREE_SPACE_GB]        DECIMAL(12,2)                        NULL,
    [NAME]                 SYSNAME                              NOT NULL,
    [FILENAME]             NVARCHAR(260)                        NULL,
    [TOTAL_DATABASE_SIZE]  DECIMAL(38,2)                        NULL)

     declare @db_list NVARCHAR(MAX)


     SELECT @db_list  = STUFF((
                                SELECT ', ' + name FROM sys.databases
                                WHERE name NOT IN ('DBA','TABLEBACKUPS','MASTER','MSDB','MODEL','TEMPDB')
                                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')

     --just to check the list                                           
     --exec sp_foreachdb @database_list = @db_list
              --       ,@command='use ?; print db_name() + char(13)'   

     exec sp_getDBSpace @Radhe = '#Radhe'
                       ,@database_list = @db_list
                       ,@exclude_list = 'DBA,TABLEBACKUPS,MASTER,MSDB,MODEL,TEMPDB'

     select * from #Radhe
```

[image]

**Question:**

Although it works is there a more `elegant` way to get this done by doing something else rather than passing a temp table name as a parameter?

I need the temp table to be available after the call of the stored procedure.

Inside the stored procedure, I need to insert data into that temp table.

is there any other way of getting this done, without using a temp table as a parameter as I did?

there is a similar question [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/168973/passing-a-table-name-to-a-stored-procedure).

Some links:

-- [How to restore a database, ignoring the free space within each file?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/121865/how-to-restore-a-database-ignoring-the-free-space-within-each-file/121867#121867)

-- [Generate INSERT list but only for non-nullable columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/163017/generate-insert-list-but-only-for-non-nullable-columns)

-- Determining Drive Letters in Use by SQL Server Databases

-- https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3048/determining-drive-letters-in-use-by-sql-server-databases/

-- PROCEDURE sp_foreachdb

-- https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/blob/dev/sp_foreachdb.sql

Comment: Move it all into the stored procedure and make it a global temp table so you can access it happily ever after?

Comment: have a look at [Table-Valued Parameter as Output parameter for stored procedure](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13782/table-valued-parameter-as-output-parameter-for-stored-procedure?rq=1) possible a duplicate to be honest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the temp table inside sp_getDbSpace and then return a single resultset.

Like this:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.sp_getDBSpace
    @Radhe sysname=null,
    @system_only BIT = NULL ,
    @user_only BIT = NULL ,
    @database_list NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL ,
    @exclude_list NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL ,
    @recovery_model_desc NVARCHAR(120) = NULL ,
    @compatibility_level TINYINT = NULL ,
    @state_desc NVARCHAR(120) = N'ONLINE' ,
    @is_read_only BIT = 0 ,
    @is_auto_close_on BIT = NULL ,
    @is_auto_shrink_on BIT = NULL ,
    @is_broker_enabled BIT = NULL 
AS

BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON
SET XACT_ABORT ON
SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY NORMAL;

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

   CREATE TABLE #Radhe( 
    [ServerName]           NVARCHAR(128)                        NULL,
    [DatabaseName]         NVARCHAR(128)                        NULL,
    [Drive]                NVARCHAR(1)                          NULL,
    [FILE_ID]              INT                                  NOT NULL,
    [FILE_SIZE_GB]         DECIMAL(12,2)                        NULL,
    [SPACE_USED_GB]        DECIMAL(12,2)                        NULL,
    [FREE_SPACE_GB]        DECIMAL(12,2)                        NULL,
    [NAME]                 SYSNAME                              NOT NULL,
    [FILENAME]             NVARCHAR(260)                        NULL,
    [TOTAL_DATABASE_SIZE]  DECIMAL(38,2)                        NULL)


    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max) @sql = N'USE [?]

    ;with radhe as (

    SELECT 
    Servername   = @@servername,
    DatabaseName = DB_NAME(), 
    a.FILE_ID, 
    a.type, -- 0 is log and 1 is data
    [Drive] = LEFT(UPPER(a.physical_name), 1), 
    [FILE_SIZE_GB] = CONVERT(DECIMAL(12, 2), ROUND(a.size / 128.000/1024.000, 2)), 
    [SPACE_USED_GB] = CONVERT(DECIMAL(12, 2), ROUND(FILEPROPERTY(a.NAME, ''SpaceUsed'') / 128.000/1024.000, 2)), 
    [FREE_SPACE_GB] = CONVERT(DECIMAL(12, 2), ROUND((a.size - FILEPROPERTY(a.NAME, ''SpaceUsed'')) / 128.000/1024.000, 2)), 
    a.NAME, 
    a.PHYSICAL_NAME AS [FILENAME]

    FROM sys.database_files a
    )

        insert into #Radhe([ServerName],[DatabaseName],[Drive],[FILE_ID],[FILE_SIZE_GB],[SPACE_USED_GB],[FREE_SPACE_GB],[NAME],[FILENAME],[TOTAL_DATABASE_SIZE])
        SELECT 
                                [ServerName]           
                            ,[DatabaseName]         
                            ,[Drive]                
                            ,[FILE_ID]              
                            ,[FILE_SIZE_GB]         
                            ,[SPACE_USED_GB]        
                            ,[FREE_SPACE_GB]        
                            ,[NAME]                 
                            ,[FILENAME]    
                            ,TOTAL_DATABASE_SIZE      = SUM([FILE_SIZE_GB] ) OVER (PARTITION BY A.DATABASENAME )
                            --,SPACE_USED               = SUM([SPACE_USED_GB] ) OVER (PARTITION BY A.DATABASENAME )
                            --,TOTAL_FREE_LOG_SPACE_GB  = SUM(CASE WHEN A.TYPE = 0 THEN [FREE_SPACE_GB] ELSE 0 END ) OVER (PARTITION BY A.DATABASENAME )
                            --,TOTAL_FREE_DATA_SPACE_GB = SUM(CASE WHEN A.TYPE = 1 THEN [FREE_SPACE_GB] ELSE 0 END ) OVER (PARTITION BY A.DATABASENAME )
            FROM radhe a


            '

             exec sp_foreachdb 
                    @system_only = @system_only,
                    @user_only = @user_only,
                    @database_list = @database_list,
                    @exclude_list = @exclude_list,
                    @recovery_model_desc = @recovery_model_desc,
                    @compatibility_level = @compatibility_level,
                    @state_desc = @state_desc,
                    @is_read_only = @is_read_only ,
                    @is_auto_close_on = @is_auto_close_on,
                    @is_auto_shrink_on = @is_auto_shrink_on ,
                    @is_broker_enabled = @is_broker_enabled
                  ,@command=@SQL 

        select * from #Radhe
END
```